# pdo too many connection, suggestion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

this is my php code. problem is db connection and db close. i have too many connection error. i used **$db = null;** but i have again error. what can i do?
thank you...

db.php

```
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name .";charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password); 
        }

        catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}


$database = new Config();
$db = $database->getConnection();
```

data.inc.php

```
include 'db.php';

private $table_name = "contents";

public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;      
    }

function dbclose() { 

    $this->conn = null;

    return true;
    }

      function readContents($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page,$category){


            $query = "SELECT 
                    *
                FROM 
                    " . $this->table_name . " where cat_id = ?
                ORDER BY 
                date desc 
                LIMIT 
                    {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $cat_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
```

index.php

```
    $stmt1 = $product->readContents(1, 0, 20, 1); //page,0,20 list contents,category 1
    $stmt2 = $product->readContents(1, 0, 20, 5); //page,0,20 list contents,category 5
    $stmt3 = $product->readContents(1, 0, 20, 13); //page,0,20 list contents,category 13

while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ //20 contents in category 1 }
while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ //20 contents in category 5 }
while ($row3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ //20 contents in category 13 }

$product->dbclose();
```

i used **$db null;** but, i have again too many connection error.  What can i do ?

Comment: Can you add debug info to log number of times `getConnection()` gets called? Probably you could benefit from using a singleton pattern to restrict number of db connections to one.

Comment: If these function are actually methods in a Class can you make that plain by adding the `class xxx {` somewhere relevant

Comment: Also make sure you are not calling `getConnection()` all over the place. Each script needs only ONE connection to run many queries through. Thats why you do it in a class and store the ONE connection there for multiple use.

Comment: If you are using the connection a lot in your script then you don't need to close the connection, it will be closed automatically after your php script executes. Alternatively, you can implement connection pooling where different threads of php use the same connection, reducing the overall amount of connections used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should modify your `Config` class to use a singleton pattern so that it only creates one instance of a db connection:

```
class Config {
    static $conn = false;

    public function getConnection(){

      if(static::$conn === false) {
        // no db connection established: create one
        try{
            static::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name .";charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password); 
        }

        catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
      }

      return static::$conn;
    }
}
```

This enforces the use of a single db connection no matter how often `getConnection()` gets called.